# Is there any way in django to distinguish if it is a normal browser request or ajax request

Tags: ajax, django, url, request

I am using django and making some ajax request to server. As the url is visible in javascript someone could easily copy that and start making request via url bar. Is there any way in django that we can distinguish that the coming request is sent by ajax not a regular browser reqeust.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tag in your ajax,and in code check request from

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use

```
HttpRequest.is_ajax()
```

as in documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax